# How to retrieve JSON response using VBA?

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I make a request to a website and paste the JSON response into a single cell.

I get an object required 424 error.

```
Sub GetJSON()

Dim hReq As Object
Dim JSON As Dictionary
Dim var As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Title

'create our URL string and pass the user entered information to it
Dim strUrl As String
strUrl = Range("M24").Value

Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With hReq
    .Open "GET", strUrl, False
    .Send
End With

'wrap the response in a JSON root tag "data" to count returned objects
Dim response As String
response = "{""data"":" & hReq.responseText & "}"

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)

'set array size to accept all returned objects
ReDim var(JSON("data").Count, 1)

Cells(25, 13) = JSON

Erase var
Set var = Nothing
Set hReq = Nothing
Set JSON = Nothing

End Sub
```

The URL that gives me the response in cell "M24":

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-10.json?latitude=36.497452&longitude=-86.949479&riskCategory=III&siteClass=C&title=Seismic

The code after Qharr's response. I get a run time 0 error even though the error says it ran successfully. Nothing is copied to my cells.

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim URL As String, json As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    URL = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-10.json?latitude=36.497452&longitude=-86.949479&riskCategory=III&siteClass=C&title=Seismic"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText) '<== dictionary
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Title").Cells(1, 1) = .responseText
        Set dict = json("response")("data")
        ws.Cells(13, 27) = "ss: " & dict("ss") & Chr$(10) & "s1: " & dict("s1")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to transfer JSON to an array (you seem to `Redim var`, as if you're about to do just that), then transfer that array to worksheet. Also, it's better to specify the workbook and worksheet name. Something like: `Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").cells(24, "M").resize(ubound(var,1), ubound(var,2)).value2 = var`

Comment: I am not familiar with the `JsonConverter` class' implementation, maybe it has a member/method that will dump the JSON contents to a range (without creating an interim array `var`). What you can't do is assign `JSON` to a range, as JSON is an object returned by `ParseJson`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by the entire response in a single cell? The JSON string?

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to pasting the response text with Excel 2003. Below is my finished code.

```
Public Sub datagrab()

Dim URL As String
Dim ws As Object
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

URL = Range("M24").Value 'This is the URL I'm requesting from
xmlhttp.Open "GET", URL, False
xmlhttp.Send
Worksheets("Title").Range("M25").Value = xmlhttp.responseText
End Sub
```

Comment: I already showed this answer in my answer where I wrote  _ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = .responseText_  And MSXML2.XMLHTTP60  is not for Excel 2003 I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not clear what you mean. The entire response can go in a cell as follows.
JSON is an object so you would need `Set` keyword but you can't set a cell range to the dictionary object - the source of your error.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim URL As String, json As Object
    URL = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-10.json?latitude=36.497452&longitude=-86.949479&riskCategory=III&siteClass=C&title=Seismic"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText) '<== dictionary
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

When you use parsejson you are converting to a dictionary object which you need to do something with. There is simply too much data nested inside to write anything readable (if limit not exceeded) into one cell.

---

Inner dictionary `data` quickly descends into nested collections. The nested collection count comes from

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = json("response")("data")
Debug.Print "nested collection count = " & dict("sdSpectrum").Count + dict("smSpectrum").Count
```

To get just s1 and ss values parse them out:

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = json("response")("data")
ws.Cells(1, 2) = "ss: " & dict("ss") & Chr$(10) & "s1: " & dict("s1")
```

[image]

Comment: I do need the entire JSON string to be copied into a single cell. Realistically, I was going to use that string and just use a formula to search it for the "ss" and "s1" values that you see in the response if you load the actual web page.

Comment: Good point about cell limit, the response given is already 31,309 of the 32,767 characters in a cell limit.

Comment: Why not parse the JSON for the ss and s1 values? I have added an edit showing this.

Comment: Parsing for those values is actually ideal, I just didn't know how to do it. My code below says it completed successfully, but it also gives me a run-time error 0 and does nothing.

Comment: Public Sub GetInfo()
 Dim URL As String, json As Object
 Dim dict As Object
 URL = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ws/designmaps/asce7-10.json?latitude=36.497452&longitude=-86.949479&riskCategory=III&siteClass=C&title=Seismic"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
     .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText) '<== dictionary
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Title").Cells(1, 1) = .responseText
         Set dict = json("response")("data")
ws.Cells(13, 27) = "ss: " & dict("ss") & Chr$(10) & "s1: " & dict("s1")
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Still nothing. The error is as follows: Run-time error '0': Automation error. The operation completed successfully.

Comment: Can you still view that URL manually ? The code works fine here and runtime 0 is effectively no error.

Comment: Are you able to issue any xmlhttp requests? Say to another site? You can grab examples off SO or use the coding is love website xmlhttp example.

Comment: I don't think I am able to actually. Would that be a reference issue in excel?

Comment: See if it works on a different macine. Otherwise, I can give you another method.

Comment: I am not able to. I didn't think about this until now, would this be because the original document I'm working with is an Excel 2003 file? I don't have the option to update this document.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Can you run any code that updates that workbook?

Comment: I'm saying that we have a large document that was created in 2003 that has many, many macros for every day use in our department. So I couldn't transfer everything to an Excel 2013 document with ease